# Bind Radscheduler in Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, telerik

I need bind a radScheduler with call WebMethod using jquery and pass Json to DataSource.

I have searched on Telerik Docs but couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

> **From [Telerik's Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-object.html):**
>
> *When RadScheduler is in Client Side binding mode (Web Services), this
>   method can be used to refresh the control and display the
>   appointments.*

```
// code ..
var scheduler = $find('<%=RadScheduler1.ClientID %>');
scheduler.rebind();
// code ..
```

Comment: I don´t want to do in server-side

Comment: No problem. :) If this worked out for you, don't forget to accept it as an answer!